# Decimals in labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, label

This should probably be a snap, but I'm stuck.  When I put a decimal in either textfield the total in the label rounds up. I would like the label to show the total number to two places. Here's what I have so far:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *value1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *value2;

    IBOutlet UILabel *label;

}

-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender;

@end


@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {

    float x = ([value1.text floatValue]);
    float y = x*([value2.text floatValue]);

    label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", y];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have your label set to:

```
label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", y];
```

What you want is:

```
label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", y];
```

Your decimal was on the wrong side of the 2 which was making it round to 0 places rather than 2.

Comment: Thanks Jsdodgers, could I ask one more question? Say I wanted to put input into value1 and the output in the label would automatically be multiplied by .25. Thus this would be saving the user of inputting into value2. Thanks again, Larry

Comment: you would need to do something like `[value1 addTarget:self action:@selector(actionToPerform:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEditingEvents];` then in your `actionToPerform` method, set value2 to value1's value * .25

Comment: Hey Jsdodgers thanks for helping me. But I think I'm trying to make this to hard. I think I would like to get rid of the second textfield and just have any input thats entered into the first textfield (value1) multiplied by .25 then is entered into the label. Label would then show, lets say a total numbers of quarters. Once again thank you, Larry

Comment: In that case, you can do the same thing just use UIControlEventEditingDidEnd

Answer (score -1):

It will round up your value with two Fraction only change fraction size before 'f'

```
[lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",10.21234]];
```